# Changing the API Format

Tags: sql, api, lambda

I'm creating an API that returning a Key and Value from database. I want to return a data by RowId.
I'm using a stored procedure and lambda expression in c#. I'm just using .ToList() after getting the return value of stored procedure.

Here's my sample code:

```
SELECT 
     Id
    ,RowId 
    ,Key
    ,Value 
FROM
    TableOne
WHERE 
    UserId = @userId AND RankType = @rankType
```

Here's the sample data:

```
Id  RowId   Key             Value
1   2       Name            John Doe
2   2       Age             30
3   2       Position        Developer
```

as of now this the API Response I'm getting:

```
{
    "Key": Name, 
    "Value": John Doe
},
{
    "Key": Age, 
    "Value": 30
},
{
    "Key": Position, 
    "Value": Developer  
}
```

This is the API response that I want to have. How can I format my API response into this format?

```
{ 
  "Key": Name, "Value": John Doe,
  "Key": Age, "Value": 30,
  "Key": Position, "Value": Developer
},
```

Comment: What you are expecting is not a valid JSON, in JSON one object can't have duplicate keys. In your case Key and value repeating multiple times.

Comment: if its not possible is there a way I can group them by RowId?

Comment: do you want the correct format in SQL or in your frontend framework?

Comment: @PSK frontend framework but if it need to change SQL then I'm open for a suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

You can write your query like following.

```
select [Name], Age, Position
FROM
(
  select [Value], [Key]
  from TableOne
) d
pivot
(
  max([Value])
  for [Key] in ([Name], Age, Position)
) piv
```

You will get output like following.

```
+----------+-----+-----------+
| Name     | Age | Position  |
+----------+-----+-----------+
| John Doe | 30  | Developer |
+----------+-----+-----------+
```

[**Online Demo**](http://%20https://rextester.com/XMP39793)

Now map this output with equivalent model in your frontend framework and you will get the desired JSON like following.

```
{"Name":"John Doe","Age":"30","Position":"Developer"}
```

**Approach 2 (Return JSON from DB directly as string)**

For this you can write your query like following.

```
select [Name], Age, Position
FROM
(
  select [Value], [Key]
  from TableOne
) d
pivot
(
  max([Value])
  for [Key] in ([Name], Age, Position)
) piv
for json auto
```

**Approach 3:**

Read the data normally from `DB` and convert it into appropriate model with 3 properties using `LINQ` or simple if statement.

Comment: Yes, it is. thank you so much for the idea. Now I'm going to make it a dynamic.